# How to select different values from same column of mysql

Tags: mysql, pdo

I have a product table that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9Ih1.png). I have inserted three values in gender: Men, Kids, and Women. How can I retrieve the value of women from the table? When I click on the link, it redirects me to the women's page. This is my current code:

```
 $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);



Dollarstmt = $conn->prepare("select * from product where gender = Women; 

dollarstmt->execute()
```

Comment: You might want to have a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Fix all your typos first. **$dollarstmt** `= $conn->prepare("select * from product where gender =` **'Women'");** and  **$dollarstmt->execute();**

Comment: Strings need inverted commas.

Comment: @Alex thax man its working thanks for your support

Comment: @Strawberry thanx bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the `''`, the `$` and to close the statement with `")` in the string filter.

It should look like this:

```
$Dollarstmt = $conn->prepare("select * from product where gender = 'Women'");
```

---

Also you forgot the `;` and the `$` here `dollarstmt->execute()`

It should look like this:

```
$dollarstmt->execute();
```